# How to create Kleisli with Kleisli.local (not local for transforming)

Tags: scala, scala-cats, kleisli

There are 2 `local` methods defined as:

```
final case class Kleisli[F[_], A, B](run: A => F[B]) { self =>
  ...
  def local[AA](f: AA => A): Kleisli[F, AA, B] =
    Kleisli(f.andThen(run))
  ...
}
```

and as:

```
sealed private[data] trait KleisliFunctions {
  ...
  def local[M[_], A, R](f: R => R)(fa: Kleisli[M, R, A]): Kleisli[M, R, A] =
    Kleisli(f.andThen(fa.run))
}
```

The 2nd one should be used as a factory method, to construct Kleisli.

Can you please offer any usecases to use the 2nd method, defined in `KleisliFunctions`, to create instance of Kleisli. With an example, if possible. Cannot get it, where this method could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```
val k: Kleisli[Option, String, Char] = Kleisli(_.headOption)

k.local[Int](_.toString): Kleisli[Option, Int, Char]  // Kleisli#local

Kleisli.local((_: String).toUpperCase)(k): Kleisli[Option, String, Char] // KleisliFunctions#local
```

Object `Kleisli` extends trait `KleisliFunctions`.

Answer (score 2):

What I can note is: `Kleisli.local(f)(fa)` is the same as `fa.local(f)`, but it's both more verbose and strictly less powerful (it requires argument and return type of `f` to be the same, `fa.local(f)` doesn't).

A potential reason to use it would be if `fa`'s type needs to be inferred, in which case `Kleisli.local` provides an expected type and `fa.local` doesn't.